# Visual Studio for Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, windows-embedded, windows-embedded-compact

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2008 with WinCE 7 BSPs. If I'd like to move on to Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry BSPs, can I use Visual Studio 2008 itself or I need to install VS 2013? My OS is Windows 7. Also, what all base BSPs come along with the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Embedded INDUSTRY 8.1 is based on full-windows and does not require Visual Studio or any other development tool to configure the OS. You can do that interactively.
Windows Embedded COMPACT 2013 (sorry for the bold, but it's to highlight naming differences) is the next release of WinCE7 (you can call it WinCE8, no one will be offended :) ) and requires Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: No, Actually I need to use [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40745) in particular.

Comment: This is Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro (I gave up trying to understand the logic behind those names). It is Windows 8.1, so you can use any tool that support Windows 8 app development. It may be Visual Studio 2012/13 if you want to use the new (and limited) WinRT APIs or any Visual Studio release, Delphi, Java or any other tool that allows you to develop "old" style Win32 apps, that can run on Windows XP, 7 or 8.

Comment: Thanks. So, is Visual Studio 2012, the least version that supports Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro? Not, VS 2008?

Comment: The latest one is Visual Studio 2013. I won't say "last" because any tool that support Windows 8 can be used to develop apps for Industry 8.1 Pro.